# Как зашифровать трафик при доступе атакующего к клиенту или серверу

Tags: шифрование, криптография, ssl

Существует задача организовать шифрование трафика.

Допустим, априори есть man in the middle, который слушает трафик, накапливает и в один прекрасный момент получает доступ к приватному ключу одной из сторон. Как следствие может расшифровать весь трафик, т.к. handshake также попадает в дамп трафика. Иными словами ssl/tsl не вариант, если я правильно понимаю.

При этом существует возможность, защитить одну из сторон на 100% (ну будем считать такое возможно), в частности сервер. Есть ли варианты организации шифрования (видимо асимметричного), позволяющие не допустить расшифровки (ну кроме брутфорса на несколько лет - тоже отдельный вопрос) имея доступ только к клиенту? По крайней мере outbound трафик?

Интересует только прошлое. Т.е. прослушивание трафика, когда клиент уже взломан и т.д. уже не важно. Объем шифрования - несколько килобайт, скажем, раз в минуту, поэтому скорость шифрования/расшифровывания может быть не самой высокой. В качестве ответа достаточно названия метода или технологии, дальше сам разберусь.

Comment: Если есть серьезный man in the middle (который может влиять на сетевые операции, а не только слушать), то ему достаточно перехватить процедуру обмена ключами (сымитировать собеседника для каждой из сторон), чтобы слушать весь траффик.

Comment: @Etki, если говорить в терминах SSL, то задача заключается в том, чтобы не допустить утечку приватного ключа при физическом доступе к жертве. То есть MiTM сидит и слушает и пишет всех и вся, а когда ему понадобится может внезапно (так чтобы жертва не успела ничего потереть, например) забраться на комп жертвы, узнать приватный ключ и расшифровать весь ранее записанный трафик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В качестве ответа достаточно названия метода или технологии

[Perfect Forward Secrecy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy)

Этим свойством обладают все cipher suite из [TLSv1.3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_1.3#%D0%A3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_TLS_1.3), так что использования актуальной версии TLS в настоящее время должно быть достаточно для предотвращения расшифровки переданного трафика при компрометации ключа сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть вообще в [I2P](https://geti2p.net/en/faq) все это убрать? Правда тогда на клиентской стороне долго настраивать.

Список протоколов, которые там используются приложу на всякий случай:

```
256 бит AES режим CBC с PKCS#5;
2048 бит Схема Эль-Гамаля;
2048 бит Алгоритм Диффи — Хеллмана;
1024 бит DSA;
256 бит HMAC — Алгоритм усиления криптостойкости других криптоалгоритмов;
256 бит Хэширование SHA256.
```

Comment: Я немного не понял список протоколов. Разве Диффи-Хеллман шифрует хоть что-нибудь? Разве SHA256 не необратимое преобразование? Разве SHA256 не подразумевается здесь в качестве HMAC?

Comment: Насколько я понял, вариант предполагает в основном анонимизацию пользователей. Изначально MiTM будет слушать трафик конкретной жертвы, т.е. жертва изначально не анонимна...

Comment: @YuraIvanov Понял, тогда можно еще попробовать изолировать всю логику в VPN и просто в случае атаки банить клиента на основном роутете/менять ключи. Правда как собственно определить что кто-то получил несанкционированный доступ к клиенту в таком случае я понятия не имею.

Comment: @Etki Да это просто, вики-паста на всякий случай, списка всех околокриптографических фич которые там принмеяются. Не знаю кто-его составлял.